# Passing Props with spread operator when using destructuring

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have a child component `C` that I want to pass with all props using the spread operator into parent component `A` via child component `B`. How do I achieve that when making use of the destructure technique?

```
const C = ({onClick}) => (
  <El onClick={onClick} />
)

// What do I need to pass through here?
// I tried ({someProps, ...props}) or ({someProps}, props) and multiple other variants but none worked
const B = ({someProps}) => (
  <>
    <OtherComponent someProps={someProps} />
    <C {...props} />
  </>
)

const A = () => {
  const handleOnClick = () => {
    setSomeState(!someState)
  }
  return (
    <>
     <B onClick={handleOnClick} />
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: B takes out someProps and ignores the rest. Then tries to do `{...props}` but props was never defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, just keeping this here if someone else is running into the same issue.

It is really just using `({someProps, ...props})` inside your *middle* component. I swear I've tried it multiple times but it only worked after asking in here.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
const B = ({ someProps, ...rest }) => (
  <>
    <OtherComponent someProps={someProps} />
    <C {...{ ...rest, someProps }} />
  </>
);
```